# Formatting Bokeh x axis from decimal to percentage with PrintfTickFormatter

Tags: python, bokeh

I am new to Bokeh and am currently trying to change the x axis of a histogram from decimal based to percentage based.  I have been trying to use `PrintfTickFormatter` but I am apparently missing something.  When I try both of the below line of code I receive no output.  I tried tweaking the format declaration and I did achieve a percentage, but it was translating the decimals as < 1% or rounding to 1%.  Any thoughts on how to fix?  I have seen a few different posts on SO, but none seem to directly apply

```
fig.xaxis.formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format='0 %')
```

Comment: You cant try the following instruction :  
fig.xaxis.formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format='%0.0f %%')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue via the below:

```
from bokeh.models import NumeralTickFormatter

fig.xaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0 %')
```

Answer (score 0):

As of bokeh 2.3.2, current method is:

```
from bokeh.models.formatters import NumeralTickFormatter

fig.xaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0 %')
```